# I want to copy DynamoDB table from one account to another using boto3 in python. but error is showing up

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I am using code below in python.

```
import boto3
import os

dynamoclient = boto3.client('dynamodb', region_name='eu-west-1',
    aws_access_key_id='ACCESS_KEY_SOURCE',
    aws_secret_access_key='SECRET_KEY_SOURCE')

dynamotargetclient = boto3.client('dynamodb', region_name='us-west-1',
    aws_access_key_id='ACCESS_KEY_TARGET',
    aws_secret_access_key='SECRET_KEY_TARGET')

dynamopaginator = dynamoclient.get_paginator('scan')
tabname='SOURCE_TABLE_NAME'
targettabname='TARGET_TABLE_NAME'
dynamoresponse = dynamopaginator.paginate(
    TableName=tabname,
    Select='ALL_ATTRIBUTES',
    ReturnConsumedCapacity='NONE',
    ConsistentRead=True
)
for page in dynamoresponse:
    for item in page['Items']:
        dynamotargetclient.put_item(
            TableName=targettabname,
            Item=item
        )
```

but while running this I am facing an error below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\botocore\paginate.py", line 255, in __iter__
    response = self._make_request(current_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\botocore\paginate.py", line 332, in _make_request
    return self._method(**current_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 316, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 635, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.errorfactory.ResourceNotFoundException: An error occurred (ResourceNotFoundException) when calling the Scan operation: Requested resource not found
```

I have no idea why this error is showing. I am newbie to python. Any help would be appreciated. Thank!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that source table exists in that region?

Comment: hey man, just show that silly mistake. thanks for pointing out. it's working now.